# Need guidance installing Drush

Tags: 7, drush

I have successfully installed composer, but when i try to install drush and modify the .~/.bashrc file it returns Content-Type: text/html when i run any kinda of drush command.

Anyone seen anything like this? Sorry can't be more specific but can get you  any info you need to be helpful..

Comment: Here is a guide that may help you. [Drush Installation](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/)

Comment: That is the documentation I have followed. I should mention this is on a shared hosting box - Bluehost

Comment: if you are installing it on remote server then its best to download zip file from there and paste it in bin.

Answer (score 3):

If you see `Content-Type: text/html` when running Drush commands, it means that you are running Drush with php-cgi instead of php-cli.

If you already have php-cli on your system, set the environment variable `DRUSH_PHP` to point to the full path of php-cli.  If you do not have it installed yet, try installing it and see if that clears up your trouble (`sudo apt-get install php5-cli` on Ubuntu).

Comment: The php5-cli may be already installed. To find out path to installed php versions run 'locate bin/php' (on linux).

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways for doing this:

- If you are linux/ubuntu user you can simply do it with

  sudo apt-get install drush
- if you are installing it on remote server just download the latest zip file from github and paste it in you bin directory on server home folder.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Both suggestions will only work with Version prior to 7. In Ubuntu / Debian you'll end up with a pretty old version. Drush is not supported by Linux package management systems since 7.

https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1628